# Can parallel graph traversal work if I put synchronized on isVisited?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, immutability, mutable

I am aware of the statement:

> non-determinism = state + parallelism

I am using an immutable Vector[Vector[Int]] as an (adjacency matrix, i.e. graph) to track the connections between cells and construct new boundary cells. Some threads seem to ommit the creation of new boundary cells here and there. I think this might be because traversing the graph IS STATEFUL!. I need a boolean isVisited variable on each node. I mix it into the Cell case class like so:

```
sealed trait Vertex { var visited = false }
```

Is there something I can do here? I feel like I should be able to enforce the usage of just one thread per task in my ParArray - then I wouldn't need to worry about this -- i think?

For more context:

I have a case class representing a Board that uses ONLY immutable collections:

```
case class Board(rCells: Vector[RCell], 
                 vCells: Vector[Cell], 
                 edges:  Vector[Vector[Int]])
```

and Cells which are rectangular objects which move around the Board and merge together when overlapping: Notice I am extending Vertex from above.

```
`case class RCell(x1: Int,
                  y1: Int,
                  x2: Int, 
                  y2: Int, 
                  override val marker: Int, 
                  override val id: Int = -1) extends Cell with Vertex
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I am doing a Monte Carlo Tree Search which involves playing many thousands of games. I am trying to do this in parallel like so:

```
val result: ParSeq[Seq[Node]] = 
for(i <- (0 until numCores).par) yield  
    new MonteCarloTreeSearch().findNextMove(board, player, 2000)
```

Comment: You say "Monte Carlo". That assumes a random or pseudorandom generator, which is a "state". How is the randomness connected into your computations?

Comment: I updated my question with some relevant details. The randomness is limited to a game loop where each move is random, and which ends when the board state detects a winner.

Comment: Actually, the creation of the boundary cells requires that I traverse a graph which has state in the form of a boolean visited field.